# Calculating area of user defined polygon in openstreetmap using python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, polygon, area

My objective is to make a tool to calculate the area of any user defined polygon on the map using a python code. I tried doing this with OpenStreetMap.

My approach is:
Open a map and select points on the map which will be the vertices of the polygon. Export the lat long of these vertices into a python code which will calculate the area of the polygon. Integrate this python code into the map so that the area which is the output of the python code is displayed on the map.
Is this approach right?

The edit option allows us to draw polygons.
[image]

But when I try exporting this, it leaves the page. How do I get an xml file (or preferably the coordinates) of only the polygon that is marked?

[image]

I have marked a polygon in umap. How do I export the coordinates?

Comment: Have you evaluated other options, such as Google maps api? If you know Python, using  jscript would not be that hard.

Comment: I would prefer doing it using python.

Answer (score 4):

The screenshot in your question shows the OSM editor [iD](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ID). This is really an editor intended to add raw data to the OSM database. It is not intended for marking things on the map or for creating custom polygons.

If you really want to create arbitrary polygons and export them in [OSM XML format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) then consider using [JOSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM). JOSM allows you to edit local OSM XML files. Please don't upload these changes to the global OSM database.

Alternatively consider using [umap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/) or something similar.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/21987/how-to-retrieve-my-data-on-my-own-umap-instance-with-api/40056) umap offers an option to download your raw data. It is located behind the "Embed and share this map" button.

Comment: This works. Thanks :) Can I integrate a python code, which calculates the area from these exported coordinates, into umap so that the output of the code is displayed on the map?

Comment: No idea, sorry. I've never used umap myself.